# Reload Div when using multiple Rows but keeping element id

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a set of records in a database and list them out in rows.
Each row has to be a unique element id so i achieved this as follows and this is inside the main loop.

```
#right<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>    { 
    display: inline-block;
    width:250px; 
    float:left;
    text-align: left;  
    height:auto;   
    font-family:Arial;      
    font-size: 12px; 
    text-decoration: none;  
}
```

Each record therefore has its own css as above.

I have a submit form button on each row whihc also uses unique `<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>` so each form has its own name as well.

I submit form and use ajax to make the current div reload so it changes color as row status changes.

The problem I have is once i have submitted this form once, it will then no longer submit a second time without loading the entire page , I assume this is something to do with the element id ?

here is the ajax

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#submit<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>").submit(function() {

                     var frm = $('#submit<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>');
                     $.ajax({
                         type: frm.attr('method'),
                         url: 'Update.php',
                         data: frm.serialize(),
                         success: function (data) {
                             $('#right<?php echo $row['Id']?>').load(' #right<?php echo $row['Id']?> ',function(){
                             $("#image<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>").show(); }
                                 ) ;
                   }, error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                  console.log(" The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown );
                } });
               return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This seems to work completely fine the first time i submite the div reloads and does as intended , its when you click it a second time.

Am i doing this completely the wrong way ?

I know i can do the submit button outside of the reloaded divs and then it keeps working but wanted to reload the entire div so i can change the buttons to other options etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the html/php

```
<div id="right<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>">

<form id="submit<?php echo $row['Id']; ?>" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Id']?>" name="id"> 
<input class="input-2" type="text" name="returnid"  value="<?php echo $row['returnID']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="submit-form" class="buttonSubmitHide" />
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your html. You may be overwriting something in the DOM needed for the form to function correctly.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing you are repeating this same javascript for every row. It would be better to print this js once, and add a class to the form which fires it. Then inside the submit function get the sub elements based on the form itself.

Comment: i cannot seem to paste the code, but basically its a <div id="right then php response here echo row etc >   then the form and then closing the div    yes using in every row but i could see it was not working when in every row whihc was why i added the echo row id part to make each script unique , but guessing this is wrong method.  so how do you mean add a class to the form to fire it , how does it recognize the seperate rows and only update self ?  i tried this way before and as each row was using same kind of element it did nothign , but i am new to this :)

Answer (score 0):

the code that you wrote is not gonna hide the `#loading` element after process.

i need to see your html code at first if its possible and if its impossible so you need to hide your `#loading` element when your process done and after that you will able to show it again.

How your code is work well at first time when loading is not hiding and its just showing?

if its'll be delete after load so you'll need to load `#loading` element too as well.

Comment: the loading part is not meant to be there, i basically have a list of records and inside each row of results there is a form whihc allows me to update status of each record so i need it to update its own div but once refreshing it cannot be refreshed again , problem i had was they could not all fire the same script, at least i dont think they could as they were not unique so the lots of rows did not work , i was unsure how to do this with lots of rows , worked fine with 1 row as only 1 record and 1 script etc

Comment: @Pete127 ok but i can't help you like that i need to see at least some html codes of your form if you need edit your question and reply for me in comment

Answer (score 0):

Put a class on every row and remove the id. Take advantage of the ability to get all elements which match a class, and hook the event to every element matching the class. Then use `$(this).parent()` in the function to get the row, and from there navigate to the children.

This is just a strategy to improve your code rather than a concrete answer, but if you follow this, it might be easier to reason about where your error is.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-action").submit(function() {

    var row = $(this).parent('.row');

    $.ajax({
       type: $(this).attr('method'),
       url: 'Update.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function (data) {
           row.find('.response-image').show(); 
       },
       error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           console.log("The following error occured: "+textStatus,errorThrown);
       } 
    });

});
```

```html
<!-- this gets repeated a bunch of times. No need for ids -->

<div class="row">
    <form class="response" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['Id']?>" name="id"> 
        <input class="input-2" type="text" name="returnid"  value="<?php echo $row['returnID']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit-form" class="buttonSubmitHide" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, i did think that the ids on each record was a workaround but was not going to work well, i see how the this parent part is working, so on success how do i make the entire row simply reload ?  row.load('.row');    or is there another way ?  would it be able to load again after this as well ?

Comment: You need to rethink what you mean by "reload" the row. the `load()` function is not for that. What do you want to change in the row? Change those elements. And then change them back as needed. The easiest way to toggle a state of the row is to use javascript only to add/remove a class to the parent row, and then use css selectors to controls what is shown when the row has a certain class.

Comment: Yes i realized this, so i had been trying to make the submit button change the row color within the script instead , tyhe main purpose was to load the div so the color changes as status chages etc but as you said i cna make it do those things without loadign div again.   i tried using $(row).css("background-color", "green");    as an eample, this is always best rather then loading div again ?

Comment: I have more then one form on each row as well , do you think this is also causing issue ? and how would i make each unique allowing for multiple rows as well , i think this is why i ended up the way i did whihc obviously does not work